# Rotating Mesh in world axis - THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm having difficulty rotating an object.  I am currently using `THREE.Shape` to configure a custom shape, after creating the shape, I configure it as a Mesh and set the position of it to:

`buildingMesh.position.set( -70, -300, levelY );`

Now because of the position of the `mesh` as well as the `camera` it appears as if its standing up.

Heres what that looks like:
[image: First image]

Now I recently added a `Orbital` camera that rotates around the world axis, once the camera moves, this is how it looks:

[image: Second Image]

Now this makes sense because the `y axis` was never configured when using the `Three.Shape`.  What I am trying to figure out now is how can I turn that object so it appears to be standing up, as shown in the first image.  I have tried using rotation on the x,y,z axis's but it always seems to only rotate within the objects axis.

Any suggestions?

Heres something I tried that I found on another question:

```
rotateAroundWorldAxis: function(object, axis, radians) {
        this.rotWorldMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
        this.rotWorldMatrix.makeRotationAxis(axis.normalize(), radians);
        this.rotWorldMatrix.multiply(object.matrix);        // pre-multiply
        object.matrix = this.rotWorldMatrix;
        object.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(object.matrix);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mesh.rotate.x = Math.PI // will rotate over x axis 180 degree
```

where 'mesh' is object you have created (you can rotate 'y' and 'z' too)

Answer (score 0):

So the primary problem here was that the mesh was built by multiple layers.  All these layers actually had to be grouped together into an `Object3D`  Which in turn allowed me to simply do: `group.rotateOnAxis(axis,Math.pow(Math.PI, 2) / 2);`

Hope this helps anyone in the future.